# Why does this sed command not match whitespace?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, whitespace

This bash script is supposed to remove leading whitespace from grep results:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep --color=always $@ | sed -r -e's/:[[:space:]]*/:/'
```

But it doesn't match the whitespace. If I change the substitution text to "-", that shows up in the output, but it still never removes the whitespace. I've tried it without the "*", escaping the "*", with "+", etc, but nothing works. Does anyone know why not?

(I'm using sed version 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.)

---

Thanks all, this is my modified script, which shows grep color and also trims leading blanks:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep --color=always $@ | sed -r -e's/[[:space:]]+//'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the --color option for this to work. The color codes confuse sed:

```
grep  $@ | sed -r -e's/:[[:space:]]*/:/'
```

Comment: +1 - Awesome.  Deleting my answer. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Because there isn't actually a `:[[:space:]]` in the output of `grep --color` -- instead there's a bunch of `\033[` escape sequences (may vary by terminal) in there, for coloring.

Answer (score 2):

The color information output by `grep` takes the form of special character sequences (see answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9943187/978917)), so if the colon is colored and the whitespace isn't, or vice versa, then that means that one of these character sequences will be between them, so `sed` will not see them as adjacent characters.

Answer (score 0):

The character class \s will match the whitespace characters  and

For example:

```
$ sed -e "s/\s\{3,\}/  /g" inputFile
```

will substitute every sequence of at least 3 whitespaces with two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --color=always $@ |sed 's/^ //g'
```

Removes leading white spaces.