# Remove ASCII color codes

Tags: java, colors, replace, ascii, color-codes

So, I'm having an issue. I'm catching some stuff from a Logger, And the output looks something like this:

```
11:41:19 [INFO] ←[35;1m[Server] hi←[m
```

I need to know how to remove those pesky ASCII color codes (or to parse them).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If they're intact, they should consist of ESC (`U+001B`) plus `[` plus a semicolon-separated list of numbers, plus `m`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943250/978917.) In that case, you can remove them by writing:

```
final String msgWithoutColorCodes =
    msgWithColorCodes.replaceAll("\u001B\\[[;\\d]*m", "");
```

. . . or you can take advantage of them by using `less -r` when examining your logs. :-)

(Note: this is specific to color codes. If you also find other ANSI escape sequences, you'll want to generalize that a bit. I think a fairly general regex would be `\u001B\\[[;\\d]*[ -/]*[@-~]`. You may find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code to be helpful.)

If the sequences are *not* intact — that is, if they've been mangled in some way — then you'll have to investigate and figure out exactly what mangling has happened.

Comment: I feel like the question and this answer are highly underrated.

Comment: It works! But it is unclear to me how the second one is more general than the first one: where is the terminal `m` captured, in the second REGEXP?

Comment: @OlivierCailloux: The `m` is matched by the `[@-~]`.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I observe. But where is this syntax documented, do you have some reference documentation about it, or is this an undocumented feature of reg exps in Java? Is it a range from `@` to `~`? What does that mean? I can’t find a precise definition of range covering that case in the [API javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @OlivierCailloux: Yes, it's a range, matching any character from U+0040 (`@`) to U+007E (`~`). It's true that the Javadoc doesn't really explain ranges. I guess it's leaning on its last paragraph: "For a more precise description of the behavior of regular expression constructs, please see [*Mastering Regular Expressions, 3nd Edition,* Jeffrey E. F. Friedl, O'Reilly and Associates, 2006](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/regex3/)."

Answer (score -2):

How about this regex

`replaceAll("\\d{1,2}(;\\d{1,2})?", "");`

Based on the format found here: http://bluesock.org/~willg/dev/ansi.html